# Apple TV TVML socket.io implementation

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, apple-tv, tvml

Currently I'm trying to make an app for my Apple TV using TVMLKit JS. After working with general TVML I would like to add a socket connection to my computer.

I've followed the socket.io [chat tutorial](http://socket.io/get-started/chat/) and the [TVML tutorial](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/TVMLKitJS/Conceptual/TVMLProgrammingGuide/ExpandingYourApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016718-CH3-SW2), but now I wanna like mix them up.

After [reading this](https://developer.apple.com/reference/tvmljs/1627369-evaluatescripts), I came up with this:

```
var baseURL;
var templatesURL;
var imagesURL;
var jsURL;
var socket;

function setPath(url) {
    baseURL = url;
    templatesURL = baseURL + "templates/";
    imagesURL = baseURL + "images/";
    jsURL = baseURL + "js/";
}

/**
 * App launch
 * @param options
 */
App.onLaunch = function(options) {
    setPath(options.BASEURL);

    var javascriptFiles = [
        jsURL + "socket.io.js"
    ];

    evaluateScripts(javascriptFiles, function(success) {
        if (success) {
            getDocument("home.xml");
            socket = io("http://localhost:3000");
            socket.on('connect', console.log("Connected"));
        } else {
            alertTemplate("Evaluate Scripts Error","There was an error attempting to evaluate the external JavaScript files. Please check your network connection and try again later.");

            throw ("Error: unable to evaluate scripts.");
        }
    });
}
```

I've left out the alertTemplate and loadingTemplate functions but they work correctly. The code above always ends up in the else case. (socket.io.js is [downloaded from here](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client/blob/master/dist/socket.io.js))

Maybe this seems like I'm too lazy to find it out myself but I've been stuck with it for a couple of hours(!) already.

P.S. possible sources to that load external js libraries/socket.io which didn't help me out so far but might help: [Help1](https://gist.github.com/jedi4ever/fbdb4938620293bfc5a0) and [Help2](https://github.com/emadalam/tvml-catalog-using-atvjs)
(advanced but uses external libraries aswell and it does seems to have nice function for dynamic templates using handlebars)

Any help is welcome.